# How can I export all named ranges in Excel to Separate CSV files?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through all named ranges in a workbook and save each object as a separate CSV file.  I hacked the code below and it loops through all named ranges and it creates a bunch of CSV files, but it doesn't actuall export any data to any of those CSV files.  What am I missing here?

```
Sub ExportAllNamedRanges()

Dim myCSVFileName As String
Dim myWB As Workbook
Dim rngToSave As Range
Dim fNum As Integer
Dim csvVal As String
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim nmTemp As Name
Dim nm

Set myWB = ThisWorkbook

For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names

Debug.Print nm.Name

    myCSVFileName = myWB.Path & "\" & nm.Name & ".csv"
    csvVal = ""
    fNum = FreeFile
    Set rngToSave = Range(nm.Name)

    Open myCSVFileName For Output As #fNum

    For i = 1 To rngToSave.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rngToSave.Columns.Count
            csvVal = csvVal & Chr(34) & rngToSave(i, j).Value & Chr(34) & ","
        Next
        Print #fNum, Left(csvVal, Len(csvVal) - 2)
        csvVal = ""
    Next

    Close #fileNumber

Next nm

End Sub
```

Comment: That looks OK to me.  If you `Debug.Print csvVal` before writing it to the file do you see content?

Comment: Yeah, I actually made some tweaks.  I'll post my actual, now-working, code below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The code below works fine.

```
Sub ExportAllNamedRanges()

Dim myCSVFileName As String
Dim myWB As Workbook
Dim rngToSave As Range
Dim fNum As Integer
Dim csvVal As String
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim nmTemp As Name
Dim nm

Set myWB = ThisWorkbook

For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names

Debug.Print nm.Name

    Dim filename As String, lineText As String
    Dim myrng As Range, i, j

    filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & nm.Name & ".csv"

    Open filename For Output As #1

    Set myrng = Range(nm.Name)

    For i = 1 To myrng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To myrng.Columns.Count
            lineText = IIf(j = 1, "", lineText & ",") & myrng.Cells(i, j)
        Next j
        Print #1, lineText
    Next i

    Close #1

Next nm

End Sub
```

Also, here is a nice and simple way to list all named ranges in a workbook.

```
Sub ListAllNamedRanges()
Dim nm As Name, n As Long, y As Range, z As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set z = ActiveSheet
n = 2
With z
    .[A1:G65536].ClearContents
    .[A1:C1] = [{"Name","Sheet Name","Range"}]
    For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        .Cells(n, 1) = nm.Name
        .Cells(n, 2) = Range(nm).Parent.Name
        .Cells(n, 3) = nm.RefersToRange.Address(False, False)
        n = n + 1
    Next nm
End With

Set y = z.Range("C2:C" & z.[C65536].End(xlUp).Row)
y.TextToColumns Destination:=z.[C2], DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    OtherChar:=":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1))
[A:C].EntireColumn.AutoFit

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```